# Get PID of the inserted row

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to insert rows into mysql.

I wanted to know the pid (primary ID) immediately after inserting that row as a return value.

Kindly advice ... how can I do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could have found the answer by yourself using Google: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below :

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

For more details refer [This link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice... It was of great help

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the extension you're using:

mysql: `mysql_insert_id()` ([DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php))

mysqli: `mysqli::$insert_id` ([DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php))

PDO: `PDO::lastInsertId()` ([DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php))

Comment: Thanks alot for your advice... It was of great help